# Clean error output in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

If any Ansible task fails, there is error output, the playbook will display it newlines escaped '\n'. For tracebacks, spanning multiple lines, this make it very hard to read.

Is there a way to make ansible-playbook to display unescaped error output from `shell`, `pip`, `git`and other similar tasks?

Comment: pff, human readable io :o) the `yaml` options is best for a flesh machine. see @countermeasure answer.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add *stdout_callback=debug* and *stderr_callback=debug* in the **defaults** section of your [**ansible.cfg**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) file.

```
[defaults]
(...)
stdout_callback=debug
stderr_callback=debug
```

This is supported by ansible > 2.0

Comment: This is fricking incredible! Why the hell isn't this the default `[default]`!?

Comment: my stdout ends with `\t`. I tried this config on ansible 2.6.2. But I dont see a difference. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I got nothing from this :(

Comment: What is `stderr_callback`? It is not in sources and docs of v2.9.

Comment: I love you. Life-changer!

Answer (score 18):

YAML output is available as of Ansible 2.5.

Add these lines in the `[defaults]` section of your [`ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings):

```
stdout_callback = yaml
stderr_callback = yaml
```

If you're used to the default output, this will change your life!

Of the [other output options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list), `minimal` and `debug` also provide nice JSON output.

Comment: I found the `debug` option throws in a lot of excess whitespace when things are not breaking, especially for debug statements. Setting `yaml` gives formatting that is easy to read without the whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

[Ansible Callbacks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks)
Callbacks are one of the more interesting plugin types. Adding additional callback plugins to Ansible allows for adding new behaviors when responding to events.

[Human-Readable Ansible Playbook Log Output Using Callback Plugin](http://blog.cliffano.com/2014/04/06/human-readable-ansible-playbook-log-output-using-callback-plugin/).

Comment: Note that you'll want https://gist.github.com/dmsimard/cd706de198c85a8255f6 or https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log for recent versions of Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for any specific task `debug` module can be used. To view the output of shell or any command , first register it in a variable using :

```
....
register: shell_output

- name: View Clear Output
  debug: 
    var: shell_output
```

Also this output can be parsed in json also. Use `shell_output_to_json`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix is the following

```
echo -en "$(<some ansible command>)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does regard `stdout_callback` and it is possible to use one of the supported plugins (can be listed using `ansible-doc -t callback -l`).

Though `stderr_callback` doesn't seem to be supported (anymore). I couldn't find a way to have separate output for OUT and ERR.