# Change error output format of ansible-molecule test/converge

Tags: testing, ansible, molecule

This is a follow up question of:

[Clean error output in ansible-playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171966/clean-error-output-in-ansible-playbook/37193330)

The above post proposed a way to change the output format of ansible-playbook once it encounter an error. But I found that it is largely ineffective for ansible-molecule (https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). When I run the test suite:

```
$ molecule converge
```

It still generates the error message with lots of escaped characters:

```
...
TASK [solo : copy wifi.sh] *****************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: #bash /tmp/setupwifi.sh > /log/setupwifi.log 2>&1
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected char '#' at 1526. String: \ncat > /tmp/timeout.sh << 'SCRIPT'\n#!/bin/sh\n\n# Execute a command with a timeout\n\n# License: LGPLv2\n# Author:\n#    http://www.pixelbeat.org/\n# Notes:\n#    Note there is a timeout command packaged with coreutils since v7.0\n# ...
```

It may be possible that ansible-molecule fail to identify ansible.cfg file under the directory. How should I configure it properly in my testing?

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty background info (dig into the doc to find more info if you want extra details): molecule does not read your ansible.cfg at role level but will reconstruct its own config file in `molecule/<scenario_dir>/.molecule/ansible.cfg`.

You cannot change everything in that file (and certainly not edit it yourself manually), but there are quite a few config options you can set in the `provisionner.config_options` section of your `molecule.yml` file. I did not check specifically but I believe that changing the `stdout_callback` and `stderr_callback` should be possible. This is described in the [configuration page](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) in documentation. Give it a try:

```yaml
provisionner:
  name: ansible
  config_options:
    defaults:
      stdout_callback: debug
      stderr_callback: debug
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to set the callbacks for the other playbooks that molecule runs, e.g. create.yml, lint.yml, verify.yml, destroy.yml, etc. ? I can't seem to make molecule's output readable except for the converge.yml playbook.